# How to tell which file a record came from when reading multiple parquet files with google cloud dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, parquet

I have a requirement to be able to trace lineage back to an individual parquet file, and to be able to perform bulk loads, say to replay a few years of parquet files if a defect was to be discovered in the dataflow.

After many attempts, the following works for the bulk loads, where options.input is a [RuntimeValueProvider](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.15.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/value_provider.html#RuntimeValueProvider) and SplitFn just `yields` `str.split()`:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(), argv=args) as p:
    mainPipe = p \
        | 'CSV of URIs' >> beam.Create([options.input]) \
        | 'Split URIs into records' >> beam.ParDo(SplitFn(',')) \
        | "Read Parquet" >> beam.io.parquetio.ReadAllFromParquet(columns=[k for k in fields.keys()])
```

Unfortunately [beam.io.parquetio.ReadAllFromParquet](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.15.0/apache_beam.io.parquetio.html) won't say which file each record came from, nor will `ReadFromParquet`, `parquetio`'s only other function.

Short of leaving Google Cloud Dataflow or teaching the team Java, what can I do load many parquet files at once into BigQuery and know which file each record came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given current API I don't see pre-made solution for this. Although you can solve problem by either:

- Extending/modifying [ReadAllFromParquet](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/fcf1698c5bf887d8a02ca87c02684e7bd46f4013/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/parquetio.py#L254) to append file name to output.
- Use [BQ tools](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet) for import from parquet. I'm not sure they have exactly same scenario though.

Comment: I made a local copy of `parquetio.py` and added `file_name` to the dictionary `row` just above line 254 as you suggested. `row['file_name'] = file_name`.  Not conceptually pretty, but was simple and worked.  Thanks.